# How can I create a randomizer in javascript which will redirect to a random webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is about how to create a travel destination generator for a school project (similar to this https://travelsp.in/) but my HTML keeps on having issues redirecting to the other webpages. Here's my js:

```
var place = ['sydney', 'calgary', 'london'];
function differentPlace() {
var randomNumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*(place.length));
document.getElementById('placeDisplay').innerHTML=place[randomNumber];
}
if (placeDisplay=="calgary") {
 return window.location.href = "http://ide50-w.cs50.io:8080/calgary";
  }
else if (placeDisplay=="london") {
  return window.location.href = "http://ide50-w.cs50.io:8080/london";
}
  else if (placeDisplay=="sydney") {
  return window.location.href = "http://ide50-w.cs50.io:8080/sydney";
 }
```

and my html is:

```
 <body>
     <h2>Discover a new destination:</h2>
<div id="placeDisplay">
    </div>
    <button onclick="differentPlace()">Find your next journey!</button>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: **What** issues are you having with your code?

Comment: Where is that `placeDisplay` variable that you are using being declared?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample:

```
var Places = ["place1", "place2", "place3"];
function redirectRandomly() {
  let myPlace = Places[Math.random() * (Places.length)];
  window.location.href = "http://ide50-w.cs50.io:8080/" + myPlace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is a little bit confuse, try it:

```
let place = ['sydney', 'calgary', 'london'];

function differentPlace() {
    let randomNumber= Math.random() * (Places.length);
    let randomPlace = place[randomNumber];
    document.getElementById('placeDisplay').innerHTML= randomPlace;
    return window.location.href = `http://ide50-w.cs50.io:8080/${randomPlace}`;
}
```

When you click, the only thing that is executed is what is inside the function, so the ifs statements aren't executed at all, only when the page is loaded not when you click at the button.